# ui.bootstrap.tabs how to know which tab is active in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have two tabs in my tab set on html:

```
<tabset justified="true" style="padding:13px">
    <tab heading="Static profit" >
        content one                         
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Dinamic profit" >
        content two                         
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

My question is how to know in controller which tab is active. I want show/hide outside div depending of active tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<tabset justified="true" style="padding:13px">
    <tab heading="Static profit" ng-click="onTabSelect('tab1')" >
        content one                         
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Dinamic profit" ng-click="onTabSelect('tab2')">
        content two                         
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

js

```
$scope.onTabSelect=function(tabName){
  console.log(tabName);
}
```

Comment: how can i activate a tab programmatically without using ng-repeat?